# Firebase-auth/email-change-needs-verification "multifactor users must always have a verified email"

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I try to change the email address of an MFA registered user in Flutter + Firebase with the below-mentioned code. I try this code with both an already registered (verified) MFA user and a non-registered (verified) user. Both of them return the error mentioned in the above title. I expect Firebase to send an email to stated on "newEmail" address like on the Firebase console as "Email address change" template. But there is no email sent to "newEmail". How to solve this problem?

```
onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

                        if (currentUser!.emailVerified) {
                          await currentUser.updateEmail(newEmail.text);
                        }
                      } on Exception catch (e) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())));
                      }
                    },
```

Answer (score 3):

When you try to change the email address that exists inside the FirebaseUser object using the following line of code:

```
await currentUser.updateEmail(newEmail.text)
```

It doesn't mean that Firebase will automatically send an "Email address change". No, it doesn't work like that. In order to be able to perform such an operation, the new email should already be verified.

To solve this problem, when your user types the new email address, then you have to verify that email address before trying to update the FirebaseUser object. So when your user hits update, you need to send a [verification email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email). As soon as the user clicks on the link in the email and the email is verified, then you can perform the update using the above line of code. So it's a two steps operation.

Comment: await currentUser!.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(newEmail.text);  also worked. It sends a verification email to the new one. The user's email will be updated to the new one after being verified.

Comment: When you call update, please note that the **original email address recipient** will receive an email that allows them to revoke the email address change, in order to protect them from account hijacking.

Comment: Hey Isa. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: I have to prepare some email with your solution. Because updateEmail() function not prepare any email. It doesnt send email template of authentication. But I choose to use verifyBeforeUpdateEmail() function which send a template email of authentication. I think it is easier than your solution. But I appreciate your great help.